# Cannot convert value of type '[DataModel<T>]' to expected argument type '[DataModel<T>]'

Tags: swift, generics, sendable

I have a data model where product can change based on the experimentation (AB Testing), so I have a struct with generics

```
struct DataModel<T: Sendable & Equatable> {
    var product: T?
    // there are other properties,
}
```

I have data provider and a protocol

```
protocol SomeProtocol: AnyObject {
    func fetchedData<T: Sendable & Equatable>(data: [DataModel<T>])
}

class DataProvider {
    weak var delegate: SomeProtocol?

    func getData() {
        //this is a async flow for simplicity am adding synchronous code here
        var someObjects = [DataModel<SKProduct>]()
        delegate?.fetchedData(data: someObjects)
    }
}
```

Finally a UIViewController

```
class SomeViewController<T: Sendable & Equatable>: UIViewController {
    func renderUI(data: [DataModel<T>]) {
        debugPrint(data)
    }
}

extension SomeViewController: SomeProtocol {
    func fetchedData<T>(data: [DataModel<T>]) {
        renderUI(data: data)
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following error at line `renderUI(data: data)`

```
Cannot convert value of type '[SomeRandomProject.DataModel<T>]' to expected argument type '[SomeRandomProject.DataModel<T>]'
```

**EDIT 1:**

Following @Sulthan's answer below I modified my code to

```
protocol SomeProtocol: AnyObject {
    associatedtype DataType: Sendable & Equatable
    func fetchedData(data: [DataModel<DataType>])
}

class DataProvider {
    weak var delegate: (any SomeProtocol)?

    func getData() {
        var someObjects = [DataModel<SKProduct>]()
        delegate?.fetchedData(data: someObjects)
    }
}

class SomeViewController<T: Sendable & Equatable>: UIViewController, SomeProtocol {
    typealias DataType = T

    func fetchedData(data: [DataModel<T>]) {
        renderUI(data: data)
    }

    func renderUI(data: [DataModel<T>]) {
        debugPrint(data)
    }
}
```

Though this solves the issue at line `renderUI(data: data)`
I get new error now at `delegate?.fetchedData(data: someObjects)`

```
Cannot convert value of type '[DataModel<SKProduct>]' to expected argument type '[DataModel<(any SomeProtocol).DataType>]'
Member 'fetchedData' cannot be used on value of type 'any SomeProtocol'; consider using a generic constraint instead
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the generic method in `SomeProtocol` can accept any type `T` but the `renderUI` can accept only the type that `SomeViewController` has been initialized with.

For example, if you define `SomeViewController<String>` then `SomeProtocol` says you should be able to call `fetchedData<Int>` which would then have to pass an `Int` to `SomeViewController<String>`.

There is no simple way to fix it, the architecture must be changed depending on what you really need.

Maybe:

```
protocol SomeProtocol: AnyObject {
    associatedtype DataModelType: Sendable & Equatable

    func fetchedData(data: [DataModel<DataModelType>])
}
```

is what you want for the view controller. However, that wouldn't work with the data provider without changes.

Comment: That makes sense :| I tried `associatedtype` on protocol but this is a legacy code and there are loads of places where `SomeProtocol` is used as concrete type in variable declaration :| and as soon as I declare `associatedtype` Ill start getting issues

Comment: Expectation is I should be able to pass either SKProduct or SomeOther object as part of my existing `DataModel` based on the experimentation result. What could be a better architecture here?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion :) Accepted your answer as it correctly pointed out the issue in the error message, I have posted my own fix I have gone ahead with but am not sure if its efficient or even right way to deal with it, but irrespective of that, your answer directed me towards solving the problem :) So thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this problem, am not sure if this is the efficient or even the correct way, but as of now this solves the problem I mentioned in the question. If I bump into any issue with this approach in future, Ill probably comeback and update the answer to reflect the same.

As suggested by [Sulthan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669586/sulthan) I decided to use the `associatedtype` in protocol to fix (Its very well explained in answer above as to why this error occurs and what it means)

```
Cannot convert value of type '[SomeRandomProject.DataModel<T>]' to expected argument type '[SomeRandomProject.DataModel<T>]'
```

But issue with using associated type in protocol is, you cant use protocol as concrete type and hence compiler will force you to use `any` as shown in my edit 1 of the question. This will obviously lead to

```
Cannot convert value of type '[DataModel<SKProduct>]' to expected argument type '[DataModel<(any SomeProtocol).DataType>]'
Member 'fetchedData' cannot be used on value of type 'any SomeProtocol'; consider using a generic constraint instead
```

on statement `delegate?.fetchedData(data: someObjects)`

Because Protocol with associated type cant be used as concrete type I decided to introduce a proxy class and make it to confirm `SomeProtocol`

```
class SomeProxyClass<T: Equatable>: SomeProtocol {
    typealias DataType = T
    var fetchDataCompletionBlock: (([DataModel<T>]) -> ())?

    func fetchedData(data: [DataModel<DataType>]) {
        fetchDataCompletionBlock?(data)
    }
}
```

Now updated my DataProvider to hold delegate of type `SomeProxyClass<T>` instead of SomeProtocol

```
class DataProvider<T: Equatable> {

    weak var delegate: SomeProxyClass<T>?
    func getData() {
        delegate?.fetchedData(data: [DataModel(value: 100 as! T)])
    }
}
```

Finally in my ViewController I instantiated the instance of `SomeProxyClass<T>` and passed it as delegate to `DataProvider`. But now when DataProvider has fetched the data it will inform `SomeProxyClass` instead of my ViewController. To get a call back from `SomeProxyClass` to my ViewController I used closure like `fetchDataCompletionBlock`

Overall code looks like

```
struct DataModel<T: Equatable> {
    let value: T
}

class ViewController1<T: Equatable>: UIViewController {

    func someFunction() {
        let dataProvider = DataProvider<T>()
        let proxyInstance = SomeProxyClass<T>()
        proxyInstance.fetchDataCompletionBlock = {[weak self] dataArray in
            debugPrint("do whatever you want with \(dataArray)")
        }
        dataProvider.delegate = proxyInstance
        dataProvider.getData()
    }
}

protocol SomeProtocol: AnyObject {
    associatedtype DataType: Equatable
    func fetchedData(data: [DataModel<DataType>])
}

class SomeProxyClass<T: Equatable>: SomeProtocol {
    typealias DataType = T
    var fetchDataCompletionBlock: (([DataModel<T>]) -> ())?

    func fetchedData(data: [DataModel<DataType>]) {
        fetchDataCompletionBlock?(data)
    }
}

class DataProvider<T: Equatable> {

    weak var delegate: SomeProxyClass<T>?
    func getData() {
        delegate?.fetchedData(data: [DataModel(value: 100 as! T)])
    }
}
```